# Magento 2 compare-products section data not showing

Tags: user-interface, magento2

I have added compare products programmatically and they are showing in compare action as below:

> http://example.com/catalog/product_compare/index/

But Header compare items section not showing. below refer below image.
https://prnt.sc/itlyaf

is related to `customerData.get('compare-products')` ?

how to update this header section even I have cleared all the cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update a particular data section by using `"Magento_Customer/js/customer-data"`.

For 'compare-products' section you can use below code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'   
], function ($, customerData) {
    'use strict';
    customerData.reload('compare-products');
});
</script>
```